# Get Package Name of Generic Type Argument

Tags: java, generics, jaxb

How can I get the package name (in general, the class) of a generic type argument? I have a class similar to this:

```
public class MyClass<T> {}
```

What I'd like to do is something like this (non-working pseudo-Java):

```
return T.class.getPackage().getName();
```

I need this, since JAXB needs this as the context path (`JAXBContext.newInstance(String)` method). Of course I'm open to more elegant ways of working with `JAXBContext`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a possible solution (if you can change MyClass):

```
public class MyClass<T> {

   private Class<T> clazz;
   public MyClass (Class<T> clazz) {
     this.clazz = clazz;
   }

   public String getPackageNameOfGenericClass() {
     return clazz.getPackage().getName(); 
   }

}
```

Comment: Thank you! Looks nice, though it is slightly redundant. But it seems to be unavoidable...